# Xpath multiply formatted output

Tags: xpath

Have a many entries in an `xml` file and have `xpath` with condition:

```
/XMLReport/Report/PreflightResult/PreflightResultEntry[
  @type = 'Check' and @level = 'warning']/PreflightResultEntryMessage/Message/text()
```

The output is:

```
onetwothreefour...  and more
```

I need separation

```
'---' one---two---three---four
```

or

```
[enter]
one
two
three
four
```

Its possible ?

Comment: Do you mean `string-join('/XMLReport/Report/PreflightResult/PreflightResultEntry[@type = 'Check' and @level = 'warning']/PreflightResultEntryMessage/Message/text()', '---')`?

Comment: i was try it before post,  not working
may be problem in development environment ... ?
look screenshot
http://www.imageup.ru/img33/3158597/screen-shot-2018-08-30-at-134937.png

Comment: That's because this syntax works in XPath 2.0

Comment: You need to specify whether you are using XPath 1.0, 2.0, or 3.1. Otherwise you run the risk that someone gives you a 2.0 solution when you have a 1.0 problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why you bound XPath expression inside single quote `'`:

Use this:

```
string-join(/XMLReport/Report/PreflightResult/PreflightResultEntry[@type = 'Check' and @level = 'warning']/PreflightResultEntryMessage/Message/text(), '---')
```

Comment: Not working, sorry, its a problem with Xpath Bulder in esko

Comment: can you show the sniped of actual XML structure? is there any namespaces?

Comment: which Xpath version you are working with: i checked with manually create XML according to XPath and its run for me with XPath 2.0: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTzz

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath expression is actually returning a set of text nodes. The way these are displayed depends on the calling application (which you haven't told us anything about). I think your options are (a) change the way the calling application displays the result, or (b) if you're using XPath 2.0+, use the `string-join()` function to return the result as a string, formatted any way you like within the XPath expression itself.